# ASP.NET MVC Default Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created a new route like the following:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
     "BlogYMD",
     "blog/date/{year}/{month}/{day}",
     new { controller = "Blog", action = "Date", year = "2009", month="01", day="01" });
```

The view simply returns a concatenation of year, month and day. This works fine for URL's like:

http://localhost/blog/date/2009/01/01

However if I enter this URL:

http://localhost/blog/date/2009

I would expect the default values for month and day to be passed to the date method. However they aren't, all the parameters on the method come through as null.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: How are they coming through as null, you should have the parameters as integers, the binding system in mvc will take of casting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show the rest of your routes, but I suspect you have another route above this one in your global.asax.CS (for example, the default route) which matches the second URL.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which you declare routes is important.  You want your custom route(s) declared before the default.